# Windows ML's OS requirement

Tags: windows-machine-learning

What is the minimum Windows OS Version required for Windows ML. I understand it needs Windows 10 SDK build 17723 and above, however will WinML apps built using this SDK work on Windows 10 RS4?

Comment: Figured it. You need Windows 10 RS5 and above for running Windows ML if you don't want to install Windows 10 Preview builds.

Answer (score 1):

Win ML is a machine learning API provided with windows 10 update and is available in build versions above 17723. The purpose of which is to carry out inference locally in windows 10 devices. In order to use a win ml based application you must have the system with the win ml API, which is available on build versions above 17723.

Answer (score 1):

RS4 (17134) shipped with a preview API and will not work for production deployment.

Windows.AI.MachineLearning is the production version of this API, and officially shipped in RS5 - build 17763 .

All of your machines will need to have 17763 in order to run that new production API .